# What is my IP address?

Tags: networking, ip, privacy

Previously I was with Bell Canada, and the public IP address they provided me is `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx`.

It was something like `172.16.254.1` which is what Google told me, and also what running `ipconfig` told me.

However now I am with Rogers, and their public IP address is something very different. Google tells me its `2607:fea8:...`.

1. What is this new address? Even `ipconfig` and Google already tells me this.
2. However, going on `http://www.whatsmyip.org/`, it says my public IP address is `99.226.xxx.xxx`. Why is this website saying another thing?
3. If I want to port forward and play games with my friend, which "IP" do I give them to connect on my server?

Thanks

Comment: You have both an [IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6) and [IPv4](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4) address. Sadly, most stuff still uses IPv4.

Comment: But the IPv4 `99.226...` is not shown under `ipconfig`?

Comment: @AndrolGenhard: Not sure if it's sad from the security perspective. IPv6 adds complexity that many familiar with IPv4 security can't yet handle, and new ways to track users.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Fair point, but the question itself doesn't seem security related to me.

Comment: Go into your modem settings and disable IPv6.

Comment: The question isn't security related, but at least my comment is on-topic here.

Answer (score 3):

You seem to have both an IPv4 and IPv6 address. If you check your address on a site that supports IPv6, you see your IPv6 address. If you check your address on a site that only supports IPv4, you see your IPv4 address. Some sites are special designed to show you both addresses, for example myip.tf.

As for which address to use, both should work if the other end also supports the same IP version. But maybe your IPv4 address is easier to remember?

That being said, 172.16.*.* is a private range, so I doubt that’s your real address.

Answer (score 1):

Your provider provides you with an IPv6 address: `2607:fea8:...`. However, large parts of the internet do not use IPv6 yet, they are IPv4-only. The problem with IPv4 is that there's a shortage, so providers do not provide a unique IPv4 address to every single customer. Instead, they offer connectivity to IPv4-only parts of the internet by NAT'ing a large number of IPv6 addresses via one IPv4 address. So a large number of customers share *one* IPv4 address. As a result, you do not see that IPv4 address on your interface in the `ipconfig` output, but an IPv4-only website like the one you used to check your IP-address will show it.

Since you do not have a unique IPv4 address, you cannot host any services. The only public address you can offer to your friends for playing games over the internet, however that would (a) require them to have IPv6 connectivity as well and (b) for the game to support IPv6.

Comment: If a game doesn't support IPv6, perhaps OP could use a VPN server that has its own IP addressing scheme, and play games over that tunnel. Of course, it doesn't work for random people, only those you know.